# How to get CGI working with Ajax call (Python)

Tags: php, python, ajax, apache, .htaccess

at the moment I'm breaking my head on this problem for 4 days. So I'm hoping someone can help me out here :)

I'm building on unix based system a Apache server to host my home website. What I want to do now is to run a Python script on my server with an Ajax call. But for some reason I can't figure it out. Here is what I have so far. I want to call a cgi script /var/www/cgi-bin/getSensors.py from the /var/www/temp/index.php file (with ajax) Here is some source code I have now:

**/var/www/temp/index.php**

```
function checkSensors(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "../cgi-bin/getSensors.py",
        type: "post",
        datatype: 'html', 
        data: {'func':'temp/get_Sensors'},
        success: function(response){ 
            console.log(response);
            changeResult(response);     
        }
    });
}
```

**/var/www/cgi-bin/getSensors.py** (this one will for now simply return the given data)

```
#!/usr/lib/python
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
resp = form.getvalue("func", "no_func")
print resp
```

**/var/www/.htaccess**

```
Options -Indexes +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

**/var/www/cgi-bin/.htaccess**

```
Options ExecCGI
SetHandler cgi-script
```

**Website directories**

```
/var/www/
|---->cgi-bin
|     |---->getSensors.py
|
|---->temp
|     |---->index.php
...
```

I as well runned the a2enmod cgi to eneable CGI on my apache server but I get a respons that cgi is ralready eneabled. All the folders and files have 775 (not as good as 755 but good for now). Ow yes and I'm running **Linux Rasp 3.2.0-4versitale - Debian 3.2.51-1**

The problem is that I get always a 404 Not Found error. Even when I go to localhost/cgi-bin/getSensors.py. But with a ls -l /var/www/cgi-bin command I can see that the getSensors.py file is really there. I think it's more a problem about protection somewhere then really my code that is not working. Anyone got an idea?  (Btw, I'm new to Python so all tips for my Python script is welcome to :) )

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? I'm running into a similar problem and am clueless...

Comment: Hi, yes did found the problem after all. You don't have to add your python scripts in /var/www/cgi-bin but in usr/lib/cgi-bin :D Remember to give your www-data user rights to use this folder!

Comment: Ah nice. For me the problem was that one of the .conf files was redirecting every cgi-bin call to /usr/lib/cgi-bin - I didn't want it to do that and modifying it fixed the problem :)

Comment: Glad it worked out for you :p